# Where's the property "context" defined in Blazor's AuthorizeRouteView?

Tags: c#, blazor, webassembly, blazor-webassembly

I have this **AuthorizeRouteView** section below, and it baffles me as how & where the "**context**" variable (line 3) is defined. I looked into dotnetcore [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Components) to no avail. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
    <NotAuthorized>
        @if (!context.User.Identity!.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            @*<RedirectToLogin />*@
        }
        else
        {
            <p>You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
        }
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeRouteView>
```

Comment: Razor views in the MVC pattern expose the HttpContext via the RazorPage.Context property on the view. Look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-httpcontext-from-a-razor-view-in-mvc

Comment: @SebastianSiemens not sure if the "context" that you mentioned is the same thing as line 3. One is of HttpContext, and the other is of AuthenticationState.

Comment: `private readonly RenderFragment<AuthenticationState> _renderNotAuthorizedDelegate;` Clearly shows the context is `AuthenticationState`
https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization/AuthorizeRouteView.cs,158fe4d0ae237721

Comment: @BrianParker but where's the naming "context" exactly defined? I purposely renamed "context" to something else (e.g. "context1"), the code wouldn't compile, so I'm suspecting the word "context" is either hard wired somewhere in the compiler, or it's being hidden somewhere we don't know about.

Comment: context is **always** the <> part of the render fragment. Render fragments are delegates. `Renderfragment<T>` is a delegate with a parameter of T called context.

Comment: @BrianParker ahh, I see, that's really interesting. Do you have any documentation so I can read into this mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

`@context` is a `AuthencationState` and one way to have it available in your .razor component is by a [cascading parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#expose-the-authentication-state-as-a-cascading-parameter)

You can look for a `<CascadingAuthenticationState>` tag in your top level App.razor component.

Answer (score 0):

After some brief testing, I've found where `@context` comes from. `@context` seems to be Blazor's special name for the parameter provided when you define a render fragment (i.e. `ChildContent`) with a type parameter, such as `RenderFragment<string>`. That `<string>` type parameter is what becomes the type for the `@context` variable. Consider this code:

```cs
@* ExampleComponent.razor *@

@ChildContent?.Invoke("This is our example string")

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment<string>? ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
@* Home.razor *@
@page "/"

<ExampleComponent>
    The provided string is: @context @* This becomes "The provided string is: This is our example string" *@
</ExampleComponent>
```

In the `AuthorizationRouteView`, the context parameter would likely be from

```cs
[Parameter]
public RenderFragment<AuthenticationState>? NotAuthorized { get; set; }
```